# Setting spinners onResume doesn't work

Tags: java, android, spinner, onresume

I want to save text from 2 edittexts(`et1,et2`) and selection from 3 spinners(spinnerm,spinner and spinner2) onPause and setting them back onResume.
Text from edittexts is saved correctly, only spinner selection don't work as desired.
My code:

```
  public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     Log.d("REZUM","notr smo");
     SharedPreferences seti = getSharedPreferences( "pavzica", MODE_PRIVATE);

     spinnerm.setSelection(seti.getInt("m", 0));
         spinner.setSelection(seti.getInt("k", 0));
         spinner2.setSelection(seti.getInt("p", 0));
         et1.setText(seti.getString("zade", ""));
         et2.setText(seti.getString("Vseb", ""));




 }

public void onPause() {
    shraniPolja();
    super.onPause();
}


public void shraniPolja() {
    SharedPreferences seti = getSharedPreferences( "pavzica", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edito = seti.edit();

    edito.putString("zade", et1.getText().toString());
    edito.putString("Vseb", et2.getText().toString());
    edito.putInt("m", spinnerm.getSelectedItemPosition());
    edito.putInt("k", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
    edito.putInt("p", spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
    edito.putBoolean("b", true);
    edito.commit();

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you need to invalidate the view after calling setSelection / setText.

you can invalidate the entire view with mYourView.invalidate(); or you can invalidate just part of a view or a particular drawable.  [See the View class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()).

If you want the spinner animation to run as the spinner gets to the value on resume, use the form of setSelection that has a second boolean parameter and pass true in.

Comment: I have setOnItemSelectedListener registered in onCreate on first spinner. In onItemSelected i set the adapters fro 2. and 3. spinner. I get null pointer exception if i try  spinner2.getAdapter().toString(). I tried with registering listener again in onResume but that doesnt help either.

I tried with: spinner.setSelection(seti.getInt("k", 0));
    spinner.invalidate();
    spinner2.setSelection(seti.getInt("p", 0));
     spinner2.invalidate();

But that doesnt help :(

Comment: Only the selection for the first spinner is remebered correctly. It has to do something with onItemSelected being executed after onResume and then resetting spinners to their original positions.

Comment: How to call onitemSelected() immediatly in onResume() to set the adapters for 2. and 3. spinner correctly and then setting selection for 2. and 3. spinner?

Comment: I solved the issue by changing onItemSelected method to verify if i was in onPause before (with boolean). Thank you all anyway.